# focus on next input not working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i want my jquery code to focus on next input but it is not working .  I want to focus on next input fields how i can achieve it?
here is my code

```js
function ok(elem){
   
    $(elem).next('input').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="first" type="text" class="validate inputs" onkeyup="ok(this);">
          <label for="first">first</label>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="second" type="text" class="validate inputs" onkeyup="ok(this);">
          <label for="second">first</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: After wich event do you want to focus on the next element, any special key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) works when there is a sibling relationship between where you are and what you want to find. In your case, you need to back up to the [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) parent `row` and then get the `next` sibling row and then [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the input there.

```js
function ok(elem){
  // Locate the closest div with the row class that is an ancestor
  // of the current element. Then, get the next div with the row
  // class that is a sibling of that. And finally, find the input
  // that is in that next div.
  $(elem).closest("div.row").next('div.row').find("input").focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="first" type="text" class="validate inputs" onkeyup="ok(this);">
    <label for="first">first</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input id="second" type="text" class="validate inputs" onkeyup="ok(this);">
    <label for="second">first</label>
  </div>
</div>
```